# How do you make a cast in Lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Taking in account the last is what I want, I get an error on the Select:

```
AwardsListViewModel viewModel = AwardListViewModel
{
     menuChild = repository
                   .menuChild
                   .Where(p => p.MenuParentAcronym == "Awards Processing" 
                               && p.IsActive == "True")
                   .OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder)
                   .Select(m => m.Description == "Awards Processing List")
};
```

The error is: Cannot implicity convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<bool>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AwardsSystem30.Domain.Entities.MenuChild>`.  An explicit conversion exist (are you missing a cast?)

How do I cast it???

Comment: Put a .ToList() at the end.

Comment: what is the type of menuChild?

Comment: @asawyer You'd get basically the exact same error even with that.

Comment: @Servy Ah the select bool bit, didn't see that at first.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect your query doesn't do what you intended - it returns a `IQueryable<bool>`. I'm guessing the last `Select` clause should be a `Where` instead to work as expected.

If that's correct, following code should work (I've combined the where bits into one)

```
AwardsListViewModel viewModel = AwardListViewModel
{
     menuChild = repository
                   .menuChild
                   .Where(p => p.MenuParentAcronym == "Awards Processing" 
                               && p.IsActive == "True")
                               && p.Description == "Awards Processing List")
                   .OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder)
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You can cast to List.

```
AwardsListViewModel viewModel = AwardListViewModel
{
     menuChild = repository
                   .menuChild
                   .Where(p => p.MenuParentAcronym == "Awards Processing" 
                               && p.IsActive == "True")
                   .OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder)
                   .Select(m => m.Description == "Awards Processing List")
                   .ToList()
};
```

Comment: `IQueryable` already extends `IEnumerable`.  The reason these aren't compatible is that the generic argument isn't compatible; changing this does not solve that problem.

Comment: So what would be the solution?